# Stripping out text characters from variables, leaving numbers and comma?

Tags: php, variables, strip

I need to be able to strip from characters from a few variables leaving only the numbers and the `£` sign (unless of course mysql can add that in itself?) and also any `.` separators.

so if the variable `$price_data contains`

`Now &pound;193.95`

How do I end up with

`193.95` ?

Reason I need this done is I need to be able to insert the data into the field as decimal, and be able to arrange it from least to most expensive.

Comment: a naive regex would be `preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $price_data)`, but it wouldn't guarantee that you have a valid currency figure, just that the string now only has digits and decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the input data it might be more reliable to remove any leading or trailing non-numbers:

```
$price = preg_replace('_^\D+|\D+$_', "", $price_data);
```

This leaves in the dot if enclosed by numbers, and would work with a literal `£` as well as the `&pound;` escape, and removes any trailing garbage.

Comment: Works fantastic! - If possible, would you mind giving a little explanation to '_^\D+|\D+$_' ?  I understand it the regex to select and replace certain characters, but what may it be doing exactly - with regards to my variable data ?

Comment: This regex in this example has two alternatives, denoted by the `|` OR dash. The first part looks at the start of the string `^` and removes any NON-decimals `\D+` (one or more characters). The `\d` stands for decimals, but the uppercase `\D` is the inverse (= non-decimals). The other half after the `|` looks for the same, but matches at the end of the string `$`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$price_data = "Now £193.95";

list($t, $price) = explode('£',$price_data);

//$price should now contain 193.95
```

here is a demo: http://codepad.org/az87F5wA

Answer (score 1):

Financial data should be stored as integers, not floats due to loss of precision with floating datatypes: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_%28computer_science%29)

Therefore, you should store it in MySQL as an integer (representing cents) using the following code to extract only the digits:

```
$subject = 'Now &pound;193.95';
preg_match_all('/\\d/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = implode( '', $result[0] );
if( !empty($result) ){
    $result = intval($result);
}else{
    $result = 0;
}
var_dump( $result );
```

Also, be careful when you perform division on integer types because you can "lose cents".

HTH